# Why a template argument of a rvalue reference type can be bound to a lvalue type?

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference

As I know, a rvalue reference cannot be bound to a lvalue.
e.g.,

```
void func(Foo &&f) {}
int main() {
 Foo f;
 func(f);
}
```

compiler complains:
 error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘Foo&&’ to lvalue of type ‘Foo

But, why a template argument of rvalue reference type can be bound to a lvalue?
e.g.,

```
template <typename T> void funcTemp(T &&arg) {}
int main() {
 Foo f;
 funcTemp(f);
}
```

The compiler won't complain the error.
Why?

Comment: Because it's not rvalue reference, but [forwarding reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), which works with both lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: Look up *reference collapsing*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read this article [Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) to understand. Here some part of it:

> If a variable or parameter is declared to have type **T&&** for some **deduced type** T, that variable or parameter is a universal reference.
>
> ```
> Widget&& var1 = someWidget;      // here, “&&” means rvalue reference
>
> auto&& var2 = var1;              // here, “&&” does not mean rvalue reference
>
> template<typename T>
> void f(std::vector<T>&& param);  // here, “&&” means rvalue reference
>
> template<typename T>
> void f(T&& param);               // here, “&&”does not mean rvalue reference
> ```

Here a relevant for your case [excerpt from the Standard](http://timepp.github.io/doc/cpp14/temp.deduct.call.html):

> ... function template parameter type (call it P) ... If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.